# There is no scalar field f such that $f'(a;y) > 0$ for a fixed a and for ever non-zero vector y

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Prove that there is no scalar field $f$ such that $f'(a;y)>0$ for a fixed vector $a$ and every non-zero vector $y$.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? What does $(a;y)$ means? What is $f'$?

Comment: domain of $f$ is $R^n$ and $f'(a;y)$ means the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ in the direction of $y$.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you consider both $y$ and $-y$?

Comment: @JohnMa you are saying that if f is increasing in the direction y, then it must be decrease in the direction -y ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many common notations for the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative). You wrote $f'(a;y)$, while
$$D_yf(a):=\lim_{t\to0}{f(a+ ty)-f(a)\over t}$$
is more common. At any rate, when $f$ and the point $a$ in the domain of $f$ are given, the function
$$\phi(y):=D_yf(a)\qquad(y\in{\mathbb R}^n)$$
is a linear function of the vector variable $y$. When $\phi(y)\not\equiv0$ then there are tangent vectors $y$ with $\phi(y)\ne0$, and for such vectors we have
$$\phi(-y)=-\phi(y)\ ,$$
so that we cannot have $\phi(y)>0$ for all $y\ne0$.

When $f$ has a (strong) local minimum at $a$ then in fact
$$f(a+ty)-f(a)>0\qquad \bigl(0<|ty|<h)\ ,$$
but in this case $\nabla f(a)=0$, and $\phi(y)=\nabla f(a)\cdot y\equiv0$.